# How to choose which image to display on ASP as its source it's defined by a VB variable?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a string variable with the url of where the image I want is located, how can I pass this value to the image? I tried doing <%my variable here%> but it didn't work.

```
<asp:Image ImageUrl="" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:Image Id="image1" ImageUrl="<%= yourVariable %>" runat="server"/>
```

An alternative would be to set it in the code behind file:

```
image1.ImageUrl = "http://example/logo.png"
```